# Multiple Webrtc Datachannels, Override anonymous funciton in peerconnection.onicecandidate?

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing, webrtc, overriding

So, I'm trying to set up a Mesh Network of webrtc clients that all are connected to eachother with peerconnectinons enabling datachannels. The problem I'm facing lies in the connection bewtween the peers. In the process of exchanging candidates between 2 peers I'm using a remoteID to declare the recipient of the candidates. This code however is not sufficient for connecting to more than 1 concurrent connected peer.

```
var startSendingCandidates = function(remoteID) {
peerConnection[remoteID].oniceconnectionstatechange = handleICEConnectionStateChange;//Irrelevant
peerConnection[remoteID].onicecandidate = handleICECandidate;//Is it possible to override this function to reach remoteID that is reachable in the statSendingCandidates function?
remote=remoteID;//Saving the recipients ID in a global variable that will may be overwritten and faced with race-conditions if more than 1 peerconnections tries to reach it when sending candidates to the recipient.
};

var handleICECandidate = function(event) {
var candidate = event.candidate;
console.log(event.candidate);
if (candidate) {
candidate.type = 'candidate';

console.log('Sending candidate to ' + remote);
sendSignalChannelMessage(candidate, remote);
} else {
console.log('All candidates sent');
}
};
```

So to sum it up:

- What is the best way to bring remoteID into handleICECandidates?

The repo with the files for reviewing the full code can be found here https://github.com/a12aleny/exjobb/tree/master/p2p

Thank you for reading and hopefully providing an answer